# Calculating a sum of characters converted to hex in python

Tags: python, hex

Working in Python I need to calculate a checksum in a very specific way. The checksum is the lower byte of the sum of the hexadecimal representation of ASCII characters. Sounds confusing, here is the documentation with an example.

[image]

Here is my code in python.

```
chars = ['L', '3', '2', '0', '0']
checksum = hex(sum(int(hex(ord(c)), 16) for c in chars))[-2:]

print(checksum)
'11'
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `int(hex(x), 16) == x`

Comment: `int(hex(ord(c)), 16)` is `ord(c)`...

Comment: To get the lower byte, use `x & 0xff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `int(hex(x), 16)` converts a number to its hex representation, then back to an integer. You could just use `x`.
- One byte is two hex digits. To get the lower byte of something, you just need to bitwise-and it with `0xff`

So, your code would simply be written as:

```
checksum = sum(ord(c) for c in chars) & 0xff
# or
checksum = sum(map(ord, chars)) & 0xff
```

And to express it as a hex string, just us the f-string syntax:

```
checksum_hex = f"{checksum:x}" # "11"
```